# PHP simple Calculator problems

Tags: php

Im having trouble with my PHP calculator. Basically i require 2 inputs, if the sum of them is equal and greater than 85 i want need it to output this message You meet the requirements for the rule of 85" and if not"You do not meet the rule of 85". Here is my code :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['valuea'])) $valuea = $_POST['valuea'];
if (isset($_POST['valueb'])) $valueb = $_POST['valueb'];
$answer = $valuea + $valueb ;
 if ($answer > "84"){echo "You meet the requirements for the rule of 85";}else{echo "You do not meet the rule of 85";}

echo <<<_END
<form method='post' action='/make-a-website/online-calculator'>
<table border='0' width='500px' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='1' class="table">
<tr class="calcheading"><td colspan="2"><strong>Rule of 85 calculator </strong>         
</td></tr>
<tr class="calcrow"><td>Enter your years of work:</td><td align="center"><input type='text' name='valuea' value="$valuea"/></td></tr>
<tr class="calcrow2"><td>Enter your age:</td><td align="center"><input type='text' name='valueb' value="$valueb"/></td></tr>
<tr class="submit"><td colspan="2"><input type='submit' value='Calculate'/></td></tr>
_END;
?>

<tr class="calcrow">
<td><i>The answer is:</td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo ($valuec)?>"></td></i>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: What trouble are you having with the code?

Comment: Remote the quotes around 84. `if ($answer > 84)`

Comment: `$valuec` and `$answer`? Maybe if you were consistent in your variable naming you'd have better luck.

Comment: hank you for your help. I have tried using this code but it still seems to be displaying the calculator in a wrong way when i open up my html file. it keeps showing this part of the code as text: 84){ echo "You meet the requirements for the rule of 85"; else{ echo "You do not meet the rule of 85"; } ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <?php
$valuea = (int)$_POST['valuea'];
$valueb = (int)$_POST['valueb'];
$answer = $valuea + $valueb ;
 if ($answer > 84){
       echo "You meet the requirements for the rule of 85";
 }else{
       echo "You do not meet the rule of 85";
}
?>
<form method='post' action='/make-a-website/online-calculator'>
    <table border='0' width='500px' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='1' class="table">
        <tr class="calcheading">
            <td colspan="2"><strong>Rule of 85 calculator </strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="calcrow">
            <td>Enter your years of work:</td>
            <td align="center"><input type='text' name='valuea' value="<?php echo $valuea; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="calcrow2">
            <td>Enter your age:</td>
            <td align="center"><input type='text' name='valueb' value="<?php echo $valueb; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="submit"><td colspan="2"><input type='submit' value='Calculate'/></td></tr>
        <tr class="calcrow">
            <td><i>The answer is:</td>
            <td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $answer; ?>"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Good job catching the real problem. But don't just repost the entirety of the OP's code without pointing out what you changed.

Comment: hank you for your help. I have tried using this code but it still seems to be displaying the calculator in a wrong way when i open up my html file. it keeps showing this part of the code as text: 84){ echo "You meet the requirements for the rule of 85"; else{ echo "You do not meet the rule of 85"; } ?>

Answer (score -1):

First off, you should be more specific in your questions so we know what to look for. I have found your issue however:

```
if ($answer > "84"){echo "You meet the requirements for the rule of 85";}else{echo "You do not meet the rule of 85";}
```

The reason your code isn't working properly is because you are comparing your $answer variable against a String. Placing the "84" in quotations tells PHP you want a string instead of a number such as an int or a float.

Replace all of the instances of numbers you wish to use arithmetic operations on with the same number minus the quotes and your code should begin to work in a more predictable manner :)

Comment: -1. Totally false. `var_dump(84 > "85") -> boolean false`. `var_dump(84 > "83") -> boolean true)`. PHP auto-converts between strings/ints for you.

Comment: Mr. Mark B, I appreciate how much you like to downvote. But downvoting and commenting without giving any indication to the correct solution does not help the OP at all. Please add constructive feedback as a reply if you feel you can help the OP out with his code.

Comment: You got downvoted because you're basically lying. Your entire answer is WRONG. And my answer to the OP's problem is in a comment to the question above.

Comment: Mark B, I believe you are unfamiliar with the definition of the word "lying". The OP's problem has been solved so I am out, but please be careful with your wording.

Comment: lying: the telling of false statements. You are materially lying by claiming something about PHP which is literally not true. My var_dump code samples show exactly how wrong you are.

Comment: Websters 2014 dictionary on my desk uses the term "deliberate", and I really doubt anyone here was telling false truths on purpose. So calm your panties.

Comment: There's enough crap mis-information about PHP on the web. We don't need anymore of it, especially here.

Comment: Thank you Andrew for your help. I think i have a syntax error cause this part of my code shows up as text on when i open my html file : 84){ echo "You meet the requirements for the rule of 85"; }else{ echo "You do not meet the rule of 85"; } ?>

Comment: Wish i could up and down vote

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```
if ($answer > "84")
```

to this:

```
if ($answer > 84)
```

The former is checking a string, the latter an integer. The string one is basically useless for all intents and purposes

Comment: Why isn't `"84"` also implicitly converted? `<?php if ("85" > "84") {echo "True";} else {echo "False";} ?>` seems to output `True`.

Comment: I don't want to tell you that I absolutely know the answer, because I don't, but my hypothesis is that that is actually checking alphabetical order and not integer. I don't believe it is actually implicitly converting it. I could be wrong, don't quote me